# Code to Cut a range and paste it on a cell like if it was excel (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, cut

I'm trying to use this code to cut and paste some data:

```
For c = p To 12
    If Sheets("Hoja2").Cells(4, 3 + c + yy).Value <> "Total general" Then
        c2 = p - 1
        dif = Sheets("Hoja2").Cells(4, 3 + c + yy).Value - Sheets("Hoja2").Cells(4, 3 + c2 + yy).Value
        If Sheets("Hoja2").Cells(4, 3 + c + yy).Value - Sheets("Hoja2").Cells(4, 3 + c2 + yy).Value <> 1 Then
            Sheets("Tabla Final REV").Range(Cells(5, (4 * (e * 3 + t) + 4 * (1 - t) + p - 1)), Cells(variablefinalfila, 15)).Cut Sheets("Tabla Final REV").Range(Cells(5, (4 * (e * 3 + t) + 4 * (1 - t) + p + dif - 1 - 1)), Cells(5, (4 * (e * 3 + t) + 4 * (1 - t) + p + dif - 1 - 1)))
        End If
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next c
```

But it doesn't paste anything.

In other words my code is just:

```
For x = 1 to 12 
     if condition
      if othercondition
         Sheets("Mysheet").Range(cells(number,number2), cells(number3,number4)). Cut Sheets("Mysheet").Range(cells(anumber,anumber2),cells(anumber,anumber2))
```

What can I do to improve it??

Comment: Qualify your ranges, those `Cells(...)`, that's it.

Comment: Can you elaborate I can't catch the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify those `Cells` *may* fix it:

```
 With Sheets("Tabla Final REV")
    .Range(.Cells(5, (4 * (e * 3 + t) + 4 * (1 - t) + p - 1)), .Cells(variablefinalfila, 15)).Cut .Range(.Cells(5, (4 * (e * 3 + t) + 4 * (1 - t) + p + dif - 1 - 1)), .Cells(5, (4 * (e * 3 + t) + 4 * (1 - t) + p + dif - 1 - 1)))
 End With
```

Notice the dots in front of the `.Cells`

Comment: I tried, but still doesn't get a paste of the cutted area, why might be that happening??

Comment: That I can't tell. Your code does very complex operations and is very difficult to understand those equations. From a programmatic point of view that is the thing you had to fix, now you should use the debugger and see those addresses to where they refer. Place a break point at that statement and use the `immediate window` to evaluate those equations.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing a point, but what I understand is that I should evaluate if the cells I'm selecting are the ones I actually wants? Because I use the debugger to keep a track on the variables and everything is right on every iteration, the real problem is with the  `cut` that I have no idea how to use it nor its requirement to work properly,

Comment: MB I was watching another worksheet on my workbook, the Qualify was the right answer thank you !